# NoScript ABE settings

Tags: firefox, facebook, noscript

From what I read, if I want to block facebook.com and other Facebook sites at all times--unless I am actually at facebook.com, I enter the following under the ABE tab of NoScript's options dialog (and enable them), like this:

```
Site .facebook.com .fbcdn.net .facebook.net
Accept from .facebook.com .fbcdn.net .facebook.net
Deny INCLUSION
```

Now, if I then visit facebook.com the scripts are blocked.

So, do I add an exception `Allow facebook.com` (from the NoScript button next to the URL box) and will this not take priority over the ABE settings? How do I know it's working?

**Update:**

Apparently they have updated the example posted on their [website](http://noscript.net/abe/):

```
Site .facebook.com .fbcdn.net
Accept from .facebook.com .fbcdn.net
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, SUBDOC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to tell if it is working on a generic site is to check if there is any javascript that has been loaded.

To check this, open the developer tools, and then make sure the only section that is selected is the JS part. If it is empty, then the scripts are disabled.

Comment: Well, duh. I was just using the Web Console the other day. This is one way to tell.